# Unit test removeHandler in python

Tags: python, unit-testing, logging, lambda

I am trying to write unit test case for below logger function and I new to python coding.

```py
def create_logger(filename="__main__"):
    # create logger
    logger = logging.getLogger(filename)
    logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

    # create console handler and set level to debug
    console_handler = logging.StreamHandler()

    # create formatter
    formatter = logging.Formatter(
        "%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s"
    )

    # add formatter to ch
    console_handler.setFormatter(formatter)

    # add ch to logger
    for log_handler in logger.handlers:
        logger.removeHandler(log_handler)
    logger.addHandler(console_handler)
    return logger
```

Unit test case:

```py
class TestLogger(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_create_logger(self):
        logger = create_logger("get-list-lambda")
        logger.info("logger created successfully")
        self.assertEqual("<class 'logging.Logger'>", str(type(logger)))
```

Now my problem test case coverage is only at 91% due missing unit test case for only one line which is :

```
logger.removeHandler(log_handler)
```

Please help me to understand how I can write test case to cover above line.

Answer (score 0):

You can't expect 100% coverage for this example unless you add a handler *before* the `for log_handler in logger.handlers:` loop, so that there is actually something to remove. But that would be an artificial thing to do *just* to increase coverage.

Comment: Looks like, now I have changed my code clear loger.handlers and then add console hanlder to it.